# why images showing 404 when used inspect with .jpg.tmp

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.6

Randomly some **product images** are **showing error** only when i click inspect.

Error details :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a **status of 404**
>   (Not Found).

See image below.

[image]

i looked around on **google** and **forums**, it was suggested it's **permission** issue with **product images** folder. but all **permission** are correct as per **magento**.

any help will be appreciated.